# decompose some polynomials

Tags: polynomials

[ In first, I say "I'm sorry!", because I am not a Englishman and I don't know your language terms very well. ]

OK, I have some polynomials (like $a^2 +2ab +b^2$ ). And I can't decompress these (for example $a^2 +2ab +b^2 = (a+b)^2$).

Can you help me? (if you can, please write the name or formula of combination (like $(a+b)^2 = a^2 +2ab +b^2$) of each polynomial.

---

1. $(a^2-b^2)x^2+2(ad-bc)x+d^2-c^2$
2. $2x^2+y^+2x-2xy-2y+1$
3. $2x^2-5xy+2y^2-x-y-1$
4. $x^6-14x^4+49x^2-36$
5. $(a+b)^4+(a-b)^4+(a^2-b^2)^2$

---

Thank you! very much ....

Comment: Where are you stuck?

Comment: The English term for what you want to do (which you called "decompress") is "factor a polynomial". There also appears to be a typo in your second polynomial (it contains the expression $y^+$).

Answer (score 2):

For

1) $(a^2-b^2)x^2+2(ad-bc)x+d^2-c^2$

think about rearranging

$$(a^2-b^2)x^2+2(ad-bc)x+d^2-c^2=a^2x^2+2adx+d^2-(b^2x^2+2bcx+c^2)$$

The same idea can be applied to all your questions.

Comment: Thank you .... you say correct ..

Answer (score 0):

Looks like most of these can be done through factoring by "grouping".  There are some ways and more practice problems here: http://cnx.org/content/m21901/latest/